# How to use MSMQ Workgroup Mode Over The Internet

Tags: c#, asmx, msmq

I have a ASMX web service that writes messages to the local private MSMQ server on the same windows 2008 server.  I now need for a remote console application to read the messages in the Remote private queue, from a different Internet location.

The problem is I need to ensure that requests are only HTTPS, users are authenticated and messages are encrypted.

From what I've read I can't achieve this using MSMQ in Workgroup mode.

One thought I had was to create a new ASMX method where the MSMQ is hosted on the windows 2008 server, which can request and respond the messages from MSMQ.

The ASMX service can ensure HTTPS, that the user is authenticated, and can also encrypt the data.

My questions are

(1) Should I be using a ASMX to read from MSMQ

(2) Whats the best way to ensure that once the messages are read, and returned to the calling ASMX request, they are removed from the queue.

(3) Are there any better alternatives

Comment: No point in solving this problem yourself, just use a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPN).

Comment: The problem I have is that I need to manage the user authentication from a database.  Are there any alternatives ?

Comment: That will just be another problem that disappears when you use a VPN, you can use SSPI.

Comment: I understand, but if I don't want to use VPN what other options do I have ?

Comment: There are none that come even remotely close to the simplicity and cost effectiveness of a VPN.  You **must** explain why you cannot use it because that surely greatly impacts alternatives as well.  Don't let ignorance of VPN affect your judgement, talk to your LAN admin first.